# Write question mark in url

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui to perform some routines.
I'm trying to write a url that contains '?' but this character is not written in the url, how can I do this?

below my code

```
import pyautogui as m
    #from requests.utils import requote_uri
    st = '?'
    url = 'http://10.100.0.34/Relatorios/Pages/Report.aspx? 
    ItemPath=%2fDBM%2fGrafico+Espa%c3%a7o+Servidores'

    print(url)

def checklist():
    m.moveTo(27,882,duration=1)
    m.click(27,882)
    m.moveTo(115,269,duration=1)
    m.click(115,269)
    m.moveTo(128,37,duration=1)
    m.click(128,37)
    m.typewrite(url,interval=0.02)
    m.press('enter')

checklist()
```

OUTPUT
    http://10.100.0.34/Relatorios/Pages/Report.aspxItemPath=%2fDBM%2fGrafico+Espa%c3%a7o+Servidores

Comment: Can you show us the output which shows that `'?' but this character is not written in the url,`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh the output simply returns the address entered without the '?', for example http://10.100.0.34/Relatorios/Pages/Report.aspxItemPath=%2fDBM%2fGrafico+Espa%c3%a7o+Servidores

Comment: which line is that?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to recreate the problem for so long but I can't seem to get what's causing the problem cause everything works fine on my pc. try raising the interval or splitting the code into sections like this

```
typewrite('http://10.100.0.34/Relatorios/Pages/Report.aspx'+'?'+'ItemPath=%2f 
DBM%2fGrafico+Espa%c3%a7o+Servidores')
```

also try adding a time.sleep() before the typewrite function maybe the m.click() is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the `?` mark problem with `pyautogui` is using `pyperclip` library.

```
import pyautogui 
import pyperclip  
pyperclip.copy('some link that has ? in it')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```